# How to indicate the parent of an object in a parent/child relationship, with Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have 2 models, `Player` and `Item`. A `player` has many `items`.

The mapping of the `Item` model:

```
tire do
  mapping(
    _parent: { type: 'player' },
    _routing: { required: true, path: :user }
  ) do

  indexes :user, type: "string", index: :not_analyzed

end
```

(not sure what the `path` option is, except that it might be used to store the items on different shards?

**What I can't figure out is how to specify the `player` (parent) when saving an `item`**. In all the parent/child relationship examples I find on the web, they just use CURL:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/authors/book/1?parent=2 -d '{
  "name": "Revelation Space",
  "genre": "scifi",
  "publisher": "penguin"
 }'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example might be what you're looking for: https://gist.github.com/demirhanaydin/6548883

By default Elasticsearch will use the document Id to handle the routing, it will hash the ID and calculate the modulo of the number of shards to work out which one it should be stored on. If you provide a routing value that overrides this default behaviour.

In a parent - child relationship, the child document is stored on the same shard as the parent document, so will be looking at the parent ID for it's routing value.

The path value is where in the document being stored Elasticsearch should look for the routing value. If it is set to 'user' it will use that field.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining how the routing works in a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Also, I had found the gist you linked to, but I was hoping to not have to do that manually: `Comment.tire.index.store(comment3, :parent => 1)`. It's sad that the method `udpate_index` of tire doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to make it work! Although I only managed to make it work with a filter, not a query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332740/elasticsearch-query-with-a-parent-child-relationship-failing If you want to take a look... Ideally, I'd like a filtered boolean query I think.

Answer (score -1):

I'm very new to RoR and don't know anything about tire so this might not help at all. If:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :items
end
```

Then the item table should have a player_id (foreign key) which you can set to specify the item's parent.

Comment: Yep sorry, it has nothing to do with my question. It has actually very little to do with Rails, it's more about Tire. Thanks anyways.